# Loading custom phtml file in the sales order create index issue

Tags: magento-1

This is my layout from my module:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="items">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_create_custom" name="custom_name" template="mynamespace_mymodule/sales/order/create/customtemplate.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

The content of the customtemplate.phtml is:

customtext

This is my block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Custom extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
 asdadasdas
}
```

I put that string there intentionally to see if it gets to my block, but it doesn't. So its smth wrong with my XML.

What i want to achieve is to display some data before this block **Item ordered**: 
[image]

What did I miss? thx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is one of those two issues:

1. The layout handle is incorrect
2. The reference to the block in incorrect

To see layout handles put following code in the controller:

```
end_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); exit;
```

Check your `config.xml` to see how you block reference is defined. (you may also share your `config.xml`). How is you `<blocks>` node in `<global>` defined? Recheck it an make sure it matches with your `layout.xml`.

Comment: yeah, thx it was the <blocks>. I forgot to load it in the config.xml :D

Comment: It happens to the best ;) glad to help